# How to remove cache list

Tags: caching, autocomplete

I have using auto-complete functionality in PHP for the text box of first name.

While I get auto-complete result of first name, at that time I have received drop down list (which displays some records in cache).

How can I hide the records displayed from Cache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's actually down to HTML, you can turn it off on the control:

```
<INPUT NAME="name" SIZE="40" AUTOCOMPLETE="OFF">
```